# How to automatically bring up CAN interface in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, usb, scripts, 17.10, can

In previous versions of Ubuntu I have been using this script to automatically bring up an network interface for a USB to CAN bridge device, whenever the device is plugged in:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug can0
iface can0 can static
    bitrate 250000
        up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE down
    up /sbin/ifconfig $IFACE txqueuelen 20000
    up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE type can bitrate 250000 restart-ms 10
        up /sbin/ip link set $IFACE up
```

This script does not work any more because Ubuntu 17.10 is not using ifupdown and consequently `/etc/network/interfaces` file is no longer used. My question is, how do I rewrite this script using the new `netplan` configuration system?

In particular, what is critical for functioning of my script above is the line `allow-hotplug can0` which detects when the `can0` interface becomes available (shortly after plugging the device into USB port). Can I do this using the new configuration system?

Comment: I assume that you really mean: `iface can0 inet static` Yes?

Comment: No the type of interface is `can`. I follow this article: http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface